# Fighting the Current

Tags: differential-equations

I am working a problem I am working on. A boat start across a river at the point (c,0) and points its bow directly across the river to the point (0,0). The parameter a is the river current velocity, b is the boat velocity relative to the river velocity. Letting (x,y) be the position of the boat, I can show:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=-\frac{bx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=a-\frac{by}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align*}$$

Then I wrote:

```
Manipulate[
 z = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -b x[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], 
    y'[t] == a - b y[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], x[0] == c, 
    y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tfinal}];
 ParametricPlot[z, {t, 0, tfinal},
  PlotRange -> {{0, c}, {0, 10}},
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{a, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tfinal, b/c}, 0.1, 20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

If there was no river current, the time to cross straight over would be b/c, so I set final to b/c as a start.

However, there will be a problem as the boat approaches (0,0), as that will make the denominators above equal to zero and NDSolveValue will start to approach a problem.

Give the Manipulate a try, increasing b to see what happens. Mathematica will abort. My question: Does anyone have a suggestion how to set NDSolveValue so that the Abort problem can be avoided (or other possible suggestions so that I can explore a, b, and c and their influence on the trajectory of the boat)?

Another interesting comment. After increasing b to about 8.47, if I put the following code below my manipulate:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{f'[t] == (0.4 - 0.01 s[t]) f[t], 
   s'[t] == (-0.3 + 0.005 f[t]) s[t], f[0] == 40, s[0] == 20}, {f[t], 
   s[t]}, {t, 0, 80}]
```

Then run this line:

```
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 80}]
```

It plots the solution, but the Manipulate program begins running again, producing this output.

> NDSolveValue::mxst: Maximum number of 370917 steps reached at the point t == 0.906172238519645`. >>

Weird. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NDSolve` is smart enough to handle the denominator going to zero.  However, it can't integrate past the discontinuity.  Instead, let's tell it to stop when `x == 0` with a [`WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html):

```
DynamicModule[{z, tfinal = 0}, 
 Manipulate[
  z = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -b x[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], 
     y'[t] == a - b y[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2], x[0] == c, y[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, {tfinal = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x[t], 
     y[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];
  ParametricPlot[z, {t, 0, tfinal}, PlotRange -> {{0, c}, {0, 10}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, 5}, 0, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 5}, 0, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, 5}, 0, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

The key bits are that we moved `z` and `tfinal` to be localized by `DynamicModule` (`tfinal` since it's no longer adjustable by `Manipulate` and therefore `Manipulate` no longer localizes it, and `z` just because it's good practice), and that we added a `WhenEvent` to set `tfinal` when we stop the integration:

```
WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, {tfinal = t, "StopIntegration"}]
```

This method has the benefit of not having to adjust `tfinal` manually anymore.

As a side note, `c` only changes the space scaling of the problem, and changing `a` and `b` together only changes the time scaling.  You only have one (nondimensional) parameter here: the ratio `b/a`.

Comment: With regards to my last line, you could just fix `a` and `c` to one, and only allow adjustment of `b`.  The minimum value for `b` should be `1`, because otherwise, although the boat asymptotically reaches the shore, it drifts endlessly down the river!  With these values, the boat always stays within the range `0 <= x <= 1` and `0 <= y <= 0.5`.

Comment: Second note, if you're just interested in the path of the boat and not it's speed, you can solve for `y` as a function of `x` by reducing your set of differential equations to a single one: `y'[x] == y[x]/x - Sqrt[1 + (y[x]/x)^2]/b && y[1] == 0` (which has the solution `y == -x Sinh[Log[x]/b]`).

Comment: The maximum distance of the boat from the straight-line trajectory (`y == 0`) has the cool form $\sqrt{(b-1)^{b-1}/(b+1)^{b+1}}$.  Neat problem!

Comment: Great answer! I tried removing the DynamicModule part and it still worked. I am not sure why that is or is not needed?

Comment: @David `DynamicModule` just localizes the values of `z` and `tfinal` so that they don't interfere with other code that happens to use the same names.  Without it, the variables are just set globally, so it still works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let Mathematica solve the system exactly?

Writing down the ODEs (scaled to a = c = 1)

```
eq1 = x'[t] == -  b x[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2];
eq2 = y'[t] == 1 -  b y[t]/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2];
```

and DSolve-ing them without imposing the initial condition for the time being (to help Mathematica) gives

```
sol = DSolve[eq1 && eq2, {x[t], y[t]}, t]

(*
Out[55]= {{y[t] -> Sinh[(
     b C[1] - Log[
       InverseFunction[(
          b Sqrt[Cosh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]^2 #1^2] (b + 
             Tanh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]))/(-1 + b^2) &][-b t + C[2]]])/
     b] InverseFunction[(
       b Sqrt[Cosh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]^2 #1^2] (b + 
          Tanh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]))/(-1 + b^2) &][-b t + C[2]], 
  x[t] -> InverseFunction[(
      b Sqrt[Cosh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]^2 #1^2] (b + 
         Tanh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]))/(-1 + b^2) &][-b t + C[2]]}}
*)
```

This looks horrible at first sight but closer inspection shows that the expression for `x[t]` appears in `y`, so that we can write `y = x Sinh[C[1] - (1/b) Log[x]]`. The constant of integration is determined from `y(x->1) = 0 = Sinh[C[1]] -> C[1] = 0`, so that the trajectory is given by

```
Clear[y]

y[x_, b_] = x Sinh[-(1/b) Log[x]];
```

Now the time dependence is given inversely, i.e. not x[t] but t[x].
More precisely, the time as a function of x is given by inverting InverseFunction:

```
Clear[t]

t[x_] = -((
      Sqrt[Cosh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]^2 #1^2] (b + Tanh[C[1] - Log[#1]/b]))/(-1 + b^2) /. C[1] -> 0) &[x]

(*
Out[70]= -((Sqrt[x^2 Cosh[Log[x]/b]^2] (b - Tanh[Log[x]/b]))/(-1 + b^2))
*)
```

Here we have set the arbitrary constant `C[2]` to `0` for simplicity.

Hence, for given x the formulas tell us y as well as t. So everything is well determined (for given boat velocity relatively to the water b).

I leave the exploration of the formulas to the reader.